# Database schema design options

Tags: sqlite, database-design, database-schema

I'm struggling to decide what database schema to use. One large table, or many small (though more difficult to manage).

I have 10 templates each with their own text fields. I am trying to store the text for the templates in a database and then when the web page is called I will show the correct text in the html template. Because a mixture of these templates are to be in a sequence of screens where you can navigate backwards or forwards, I need to be able to sequence them, I can only think of adding a page_number column. I also would like to re-order them and delete them as necessary using the page_number column.

I was planning to do all this in a web application without the need for a standard folder/web page structure, like a small CMS system.

option 1,
I can create one large table with many columns, lot's of which will be empty, over half with each row. Is this bad?

option 2,
I could create many tables using only the relevant template columns required.
The problem I see with this, is the headache of repopulating a column in each table when I delete a row, because I need to re-sequence a column that represents page numbers. Which I reduce if I use one large table.

I've thought of moving page numbers into another table called page_order but I cannot think of a way to maintain an effective relationship between the other tables if I make changes.

I'm yet to figure out how to re-sequence a column in a database when a row is deleted. Surely this is a common problem!?

Thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

Have one table that contains one row per template. It might look like:

```
id (INT, auto-increment)
page_order (INT, unique key here, so pages cannot have the same number)
field1 (STRING, name of the text field) 
value1 (STRING, contents of the text field)
field2
value2
```

Then you have to decide the maximum fields that any page can have (N) and keep adding field/value columns up to N.

The advantage of this is you have one table that isn't sparsely populated (as long as the templates have about the same number of fields, even if the names of those fields are different).

If you want to make an improvement to his (maybe not necessary for a small amount of data) you could change field to an INT id and connect it to a lookup table that contains (field_id, field_name).

Comment: Hi Thanks for the feedback, for practise I think I'm going to work both solutions out! This way I can gain experience as database planning is more complicated that I suspected. I've started working with multiple tables because I've figured that the majority of columns would be empty for a certain template that's rare, but has 10 columns in. Though I still cannot find any evidence of empty columns degrading performance or any other negligible effects?